# How to run a permissioned ethereum blockchain?

Tags: private-blockchain, eris-industries, permissioned-chain

As far my understanding to Ethereum, it is public chains.but how can it support permission machnism in detail, even from source code perspective. Can Ethereum be used for establishing private blockchain.

If I want to  test for establishing private chain for private company stock registration instead of mining, meanwhile administrator's permission also need. Would you advice me for doing that. what technology does Ethereum  use for doing that

Comment: Thanks. If I want to  do a test for establishing private chain for private company stock registration instead of mining, meanwhile administrator's permission also need. Would you advice me for doing that. what technology does Ethereum  use for doing that

Comment: check out [Eris toolkit for premissioned blockchains](https://docs.erisindustries.com/explainers/permissioned_blockchains/). Maybe that helps.

Comment: Private and Permissioned blockchains are not the same. Check [this](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/8072/2460)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need differentiate private blockchain and permissioned blockchain.
You can see here [Private vs Permissioned blockchains](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8072/private-vs-permissioned-blockchains?rq=1).

If you want create a private network with Ethereum here ([Permissioned blockchain in ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10706/permissioned-blockchain-in-ethereum/13932#13932)).

If you want to create a permissioned blockchain, you use Quorom, Hydrachain or ErisDB.

Answer (score 1):

Parity allows you to select different consensus engines which are not based on Proof of Work, such as [Aura](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Aura) (Proof of Authority) or [Tendermint](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Consensus-Engines#tendermint) (Practical Byzantine Fault Tolerance, experimental). They are also referred to as *validator engines*, because only defined [validator sets](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Validator-Set) are allowed to participate in consensus.

This enables you to run a permissioned Ethereum blockchain.

*Disclosure, I work for Parity.*

Comment: Is there any documentation on setting up a private chain with these validators?
It's not simply done in the genesis.json file I assume..

Comment: It is! https://wiki.parity.io/Demo-PoA-tutorial