# Permissioned blockchain in ethereum

Tags: genesis, permissioned-chain

If I create a new Ethereum blockchain using a new genesis block and network id, is it possible to restrict the access to it only to specific nodes?

In other words, can I avoid that undesirable nodes with the same genesis block and same network id attach to my blockchain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network parameters do not authenticate or authorize nodes joining the network. Anybody can join your network as long as they know IP address of your node.

There are couple of EVM implementations with proper node authentication and authorization

- ErisDB https://monax.io/platform/db/?redirect_from_eris=true
- Quorum https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/

Comment: if we put maxpeer=2 and we add 2 nodes is it possible for a third party to join the network and synch?

Comment: I would say "yes", but because of network connectivity issues, denial of service attacks and nodes rebooting this would be very, very, insecure and could be hacked in in couple of minutes.

Comment: You can also check [Pantheon](https://github.com/PegaSysEng/pantheon). It supports [local](http://docs.pantheon.pegasys.tech/en/stable/Permissions/Local-Permissioning/) and [onchain](http://docs.pantheon.pegasys.tech/en/stable/Permissions/Onchain-Permissioning/) permissioning.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you could setup your private chain and indicate which nodes are allowed to connect to your blockchain.

1-define the same genesis file and the same network id.

2-use the following options to restrict the  allowed node :

`--nodiscover` : Use this option to make sure that your node is not discoverable by people who do not manually add you.

`--maxpeers` value      Maximum number of network peers (network disabled if set to 0) (default: 25)

you could also define the desired nodes on geth boot using :

`--bootnodes` value     Comma separated enode URLs for P2P discovery bootstrap

or do it after geth launch by using `admin.addNode()`

you could check the connected node using `admin.peers`